# How can I change the sound device used by one application?

Tags: sound, soundcard

I'm trying to play some sounds using my standard sound card while playing some other sounds over another soundcard. 
How can I set which application uses which soundcard. I only found ways to set all applications to use one of the two.

Answer (score 4):

We can direct the output of a running application to another soundcard or sink with [pavucontrol](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/pavucontrol) [image: Install pavucontrol] as depicted here:

[image]

These settings are valid as long as the application is running, however they can not (yet) be made permanent.

Comment: Very cool! I wish they had that for OS X!